# Audio ducking in Premiere Pro

Tags: audio, mixing

Many high end mixing stations have a feature that makes the music quieter when a mic is spoken into.

I would like to acheive something similar in premier.  I am editing a video that has a track playing in the background but there's periodically other audio throughout.  Is it possible for the background track to become quieter when one of the other primary tracks has audio playing?

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're looking for is called [Audio Ducking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ducking) and can be achieved by applying a side-chain compressor to your background track or by key framing your background audio volume to lower when the other track is playing.

A side-chain compressor monitors the amplitude of `signal B` and applies compression based on that to `signal A`. So if `signal B` will have audio in it, `signal A` will be quieter for that moment. 
Get a VST or AU [side-chain compressor](http://bedroomproducersblog.com/2010/11/10/bpb-freeware-studio-best-free-sidechain-compressor-vst-plugins/), apply it to your background track (`signal A`) and set the other primary track as the side-chain input (`signal B`). 
If you have multiple commentary tracks, either merge them to one, or apply the effect multiple times to `signal A` but with different side-chain inputs.

The other method involves keyframing your audio track volume and is completely explained in this [Adobe Forum post titled: Adjusting Audio Volume Levels](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/792215?tstart=0)

Comment: To add a little to what Bart Arondson is saying.  If you aren't familiar with compression, it is when the signal level (effectively relates to volume in the real world, but there are reasons it isn't called volume) is reduced by a ratio when ever it exceeds a certain level.  For example, if something is compressed with a 4:1 ratio, then once the signal level gets loud enough (the threshold) then for every 4 db of additional signal, the output will be turned down to only give 1 additional db of signal.  This gives a more natural sound than just doing a hard cut to additional "volume".